# Oracle pop-out input

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to do a pop-out input in Oracle. I'm using `:DS.SPECIALISE` and `:AD.STATUS` as input.

But once I submit my input value, it shows

> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

and fails to generate the output.

Here is my SQL query:

```
select DT.DOCTOR_ID, DT.NAME, AD.STATUS, DS.SPECIALISE
from DOCTOR_SPECIALISE DS
INNER JOIN DOCTOR DT
  on DS.DOCTOR_ID = DT.DOCTOR_ID
INNER JOIN AVAILABILITY_DATE AD
  on DT.DOCTOR_ID = AD.DOCTOR_ID
WHERE :DS.SPECIALISE
  AND :AD.STATUS;
```

I had done in this way, but i don't understand why i'm using inner join can't generate data.

```
Select DT.DOCTOR_ID, DT.NAME, AD.STATUS, DS.SPECIALISE from DOCTOR_SPECIALISE DS, DOCTOR DT, AVAILABILITY_DATE AD
WHERE :SPECIALISE=DS.SPECIALISE AND 
DT.DOCTOR_ID=DS.DOCTOR_ID AND :STATUS=AD.STATUS;
```

Comment: what is the type of :DS.SPECIALISE and :AD.STATUS? what do you need to do with the WHERE condition ?

Comment: Both of the type are varchar. 
Im using WHERE :DS.SPECIALISE AND :AD.STATUS; to allow people input the value to search.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT DT.DOCTOR_ID, DT.NAME, AD.STATUS, DS.SPECIALISE 
  FROM DOCTOR_SPECIALISE DS, DOCTOR DT, AVAILABILITY_DATE AD
 WHERE :SPECIALISE=DS.SPECIALISE 
   AND DT.DOCTOR_ID=DS.DOCTOR_ID 
   AND :STATUS=AD.STATUS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like the following:

```
Select DT.DOCTOR_ID, DT.NAME, AD.STATUS, DS.SPECIALISE
from DOCTOR_SPECIALISE DS
 INNER JOIN DOCTOR DT
  on DS.DOCTOR_ID = DT.DOCTOR_ID
 INNER JOIN AVAILABILITY_DATE AD
  on DT.DOCTOR_ID = AD.DOCTOR_ID
WHERE :SPECIALISE = DS.SPECIALISE
  AND :STATUS = AD.STATUS;
```

Comment: check your input variables; are you sure you can refer them as :DS.SPECIALISE and :AD.STATUS?

Comment: Not really understand how to check they can refer as my :DS.SPECIALISE and :AD.STATUS any guide?

Comment: Try the query with fixed values instead of the variables; if it works, the query is OK and you have to understand hot to refer your input values,

Comment: Are you allowed to have two part parameter names, incl `DS` and `SPECIALISE`? I'd try `:DS_SPECIALIS`.

Comment: I'm new to oracle, not really sure hows it function... :(

Comment: its weird when i'm using this way and successfully generate output.
*Check at question i had edited*

Comment: The query is OK; you simply have to use :STATUS and :SPECIALISE, instead of :DS.SPECIALISE and :AD.STATUS. Just edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that this in invalid syntax :

```
WHERE :DS.SPECIALISE
  AND :AD.STATUS;
```

after :DS_SPECIALISE the parser is expecting a relational operator not the reserved word AND

Aleksej's answer above fixes that for you